# I am getting the Error during creating the JSON to APEX?

Tags: apex, json, custom

```
public class etTemplateNew{
    public String contactId;    //003m000000PM2HrAAL
    public Integer requestId = 0;  //1
    public cls_templateAttributes templateAttributes;
    public String templateId;   //1_Month_Pay Stub
    public String toAddress;    //ssoman@applieddatafinance.com

    }
        public etTemplateNew (String contactId, Integer requestId){
            this.contactId = contactId;
            this.requestId = requestId;
        }
        public etTemplateNew (String templateId, toAddress)
        {
            this.templateId = templateId;
            this.toAddress = toAddress;
            }
        public class cls_templateAttributes
        {
            public String Customer_Name;
            public cls_templateAttributes(String Customer_Name){
                this.Customer_Name = Customer_Name;
            }
        }


    }
```

**Error**

> I am getting the error : unexpected token: public

Comment: I am getting the error : unexpected token: public

Comment: Remove the extra right curly bracket ( `}` ) just after the line `public String toAddress;`

Comment: line no 8 `}` is extra closing bracket. Just remove that.